# Search string field in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have my `device_model` field, for example like this:

LENOVO IdeaTab A3000-H[graphicsDeviceName: PowerVR SGX 544MP;   graphicsDeviceVendor: Imagination Technologies; graphicsDeviceVersion: OpenGL ES 2.0 build 1.9@2204701; graphicsMemorySize: 60; operatingSystem: Android OS 4.2.2 / API-17 (JDQ39/A3000_A422_003_026_130823_WW_SMS_FUSE); processorCount: 4; processorType: ARMv7 VFPv3 NEON; systemMemorySize: 974; maxTextureSize: 4096]

I want to aggregate to know devices:

```
"aggs" : {
        "devices" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "device_model",
                "size": 0
            }
        }
    }
```

But it returns me only one words aggregation like this:

```
"aggregations": {
      "user-ids": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "android",
               "doc_count": 20851
            },
            {
               "key": "api",
               "doc_count": 20851
            },
            {
               "key": "es",
               "doc_count": 20851
            },
```

But I want to see whole field. What should I do for elasticsearch not divide my string field when I aggregated?

Comment: What's the mapping of the device_model field?

Comment: @AndreiStefan "warhammer": {
      "mappings": {
         "logs": {
            "properties": {
               "device_model": {
                  "type": "string"
               },

Comment: Change the mapping of the field to be `"device_model": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        }` and then use the following for your aggregation: `"aggs" : {
        "devices" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "device_model.raw",
                "size": 0
            }
        }
    }`

Comment: @AndreiStefan That would work for the aggregation, but you'll have to reindex all the data (ref : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/mapping.html#_updating_existing_mappings)

Comment: @AndreiStefan I've tried 
PUT /warhammer
{
    "device_model": { "type": "string",
    "fields": { "raw":
    { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" } } }
}
and it gives me error
{
   "error": "RemoteTransportException[[kibana.herocraft.com][inet[/192.168.0.1:9300]][indices:admin/create]]; nested: IndexAlreadyExistsException[[warhammer] already exists]; ",
   "status": 400
}

Comment: I think the error message is self-explanatory. Do please read the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#updating-field-mappings). Delete the index, create it new again with the new mapping for that field, re-index the documents, test the query. Or go over the link I provided and change the mapping for that field only.